# How would I use inotifywait to execute a command if a file in a directory is created, deleted or modified?

Tags: shell-script, inotify

Here is the shell script I've got so far. I want it to check recursively, hence the following options:

- `-r` for recursive
- `-m` for monitoring
- `-e` for event notification and tracking

For a reason unknown to me, this approach isn't working. I'm creating/modifying/deleting files using rm/nano/touch etc and in the terminal I ran the script I get a message saying that a particular operation has been used, where it was used and the file it was used on e.g. `/home/stephen/ CREATE test` where test is the file I've created using touch.

```
#!/bin/sh
while inotifywait -mre create,delete,modify /home;do
       echo "test"
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! Can you show exactly how you create, delete or modify files to trigger this? Because "not working" is usually not specific enough for anyone else to debug the issue. Other possible issues include whether you have access to the files and remote filesystems.

Comment: Just updated my origional post explaining what's going on. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: OK, so it prints the expected message when you create a file. What is not working?

Comment: It's not printing my "test" message

Comment: "/home/stephen/ CREATE test" means that "/home/stephen/test" was created. Is that the confusing thing?

Comment: `while inotifywait -r . -e create,delete,modify; do { echo "test"; }; done`, tested without -m which works under zsh 5.6.2

Comment: the /home/stephen/ Create test is the name of a file in that case, I'm trying to get the script to just output something I have predifined to the terminal every time anything in the /home directory is modified, deleted or created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe inotifywait -m does not exit causing the while-loop not to run as expected.

`while inotifywait -r /home -e create,delete,modify; do { echo "test"; }; done` however should work as you expect it.

Comment: hmmm, I've just tested this and seems like you're right. Do you know of a way for this to repeat the echo "test" any time a new modification/deletion or creation is made?

Comment: Do you want to omit the message of inotifywait and only echo from inside of the loop? The current command does already output echo. You can always use -q to silence inotifywait.

Comment: @Stephen and if you do not want any output from inotifywait, you can use /dev/zero to get rid of the event. `while $(inotifywait -q -r . -e create,delete,modify >/dev/null); do { echo "TEST"; }; done`

Comment: I think I've just found my solution, I did what you suggested but put that in a while true loop and it works as I hoped, Thank you very much. One final question is there a way to omit the /home/stephen/ CREATE (dir/filename), -q removed the "setting up watches" and "watches setup", Just wondering if I can remove this "/home/stephen/ ......" part

Comment: Nvm just re-read the man page, tyvm

Answer (score 0):

I would change where you do your loop. And I'd keep monitor mode so that you don't have to keep starting up the `inotifywait` process so that you limit the chance of missing an event:

```bash
inotifywait -mre create,delete,modify /home | while read dirname events basename;
do
       echo "test $dirname $events $basename"
done
```